# is there a tool for finding shared library symbol conflicts?

Tags: linux, shared-library

I have a crash in some software I am writing which I suspect may be caused by symbol conflicts between two different shared libraries (when I disable one of the shared libraries the other starts working).

is there a tool I can use that will look through the libraries loaded by a program and tell me if there are any symbols defined in more than one library?

Answer (score 3):

There are commonly-available utilities which can be used in a shell script to solve the problem (though I don't recall seeing a script which combines them to solve the problem).  The **`nm`** utility is used to find symbols in an object file or executable.  On most systems, **`ldd`** (`otool` on macOS) shows the shared libraries used by an executable.  For the former, for example, I have a script ([*`listused.sh`*](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/listused.sh)) in ncurses which lists all of the symbols in its libraries and whether those are testable by a program using the libraries (see [report](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/ab10836a5884f5ca9a8c09110ce7486a9cbad9ec/test/README#L74) in [**`test/README`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/README)).

The `-C` option is useful (if you're interested in C++ libraries), but the libraries may be *stripped* (lacking debugging information).  However, the **`-D`** option (available on "recent" systems, e.g., almost anything updated in the past 10-15 years) provides symbols for *dynamic* libraries:

- [GNU binutils](https://github.com/gittup/binutils/blob/252b5132c753830d5fd56823373aed85f2a0db63/binutils/nm.1), since 1999

> Display the dynamic symbols rather than the normal symbols.  This is
> only meaningful for dynamic objects, such as certain types of shared
> libraries.

- [ELF Toolchain](https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/nm/), since 2008

> Only display dynamic symbols.
> This option is only meaningful for shared libraries.

- [Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/nm-1.html) (and [Solaris 10](https://docs.huihoo.com/solaris/10/english/html/816-5165/nm-1.html#scrolltoc)):

> Displays the `SHT_DYNSYM` symbol information. This is the symbol table used by ld.so.1 and is present even in stripped dynamic executables. If **`–D`** is not specified, the default behavior is to display the `SHT_SYMTAB` symbol information.

This is not a feature of less recent systems, at least according to their documentation:

- [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/n_commands/nm.html)
- [HP-UX](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/nm.1.html)

(someone might know offhand the timeline for introducing the feature).

I've used the feature in a few scripts such as [`analyze-curses-symbols`](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:analyze-curses-symbols).

Further reading:

- [Shared Library Symbol Conflicts (on Linux)](https://holtstrom.com/michael/blog/post/437/Shared-Library-Symbol-Conflicts-%28on-Linux%29.html)  provides examples showing how to use `nm` for this purpose.
- [Chapter 3. Using Dynamic Shared Objects](http://csweb.cs.wfu.edu/%7Etorgerse/Kokua/More_SGI/007-2360-010/sgi_html/ch03.html) from an old SGI manual mentions that `elfdump` has a relevant option:

> If you use the -quickstart_info option, ld tells you if conflicts arise. It also tells you to run elfdump with the -Dc option to find the conflicts. See the elfdump(1) man page for more information about how to read the output produced by elfdump.

- However, elfdump is not standardized (even to the extent that [**`nm`**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html) is), and that **`-Dc`** is not found in other implementations such as [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/elfdump-1.html), for Solaris.  (There are [related](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/conflict-1.html#scrolltoc) programs for Solaris).

Answer (score 0):

`nm -C library.so | grep -i symbol`

is probably what you're looking for. It might not work for stripped libraries though.

Comment: This only works if the shared library is not stripped.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux dynamic linker also provides some methods do debug such issues. E.g. you can `export LD_DEBUG=bindings` to get lots of information on all symbol bindings. Collect all those outputs in a file, and compare the output in the different scenarios, and you will notice some symbols linking to different files. See the [ld.so documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for more options.

For example, we were tracking down a crash when we linked the TensorFlow into our binary, and also used some embedded Python. We reduced the crash to `import hashlib`. It does not crash when not linking TensorFlow. (You find this also being reported [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/3543) and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21588).)

With linking TF, I got outputs like this:

```
2306643:     binding file /u/zeyer/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0] to /u/zeyer/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so.2 [0]: normal symbol `EVP_MD_size' [OPENSSL_1_1_0]
```

Just running `python -c "import hashlib"` gives me outputs like this:

```
   2307740:     binding file /u/zeyer/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0] to /work/tools/users/zeyer/linuxbrew/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 [0]: normal symbol `EVP_MD_size' [OPENSSL_1_1_0]
```

As you see, in the case with TF, it finds those OpenSSL related symbols in `libtensorflow_framework.so.2`, in the other case, it finds them in `libcrypto.so.1.1` (as it should be).

Our solution here was to add `-L/work/tools/users/zeyer/linuxbrew/lib -Wl,-rpath,/work/tools/users/zeyer/linuxbrew/lib -Wl,-no-as-needed -lcrypto` to our linker flags, before we link the TF library. So we enforce that `libcrypto.so.1.1` is loaded first. That solves the problem. See [here](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/cpp-link-py-tf-compile.py) for my compile script.